# How do I run an array through an IF statement in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an application that highlights user messages from a stream based on whether or not the user has been 'vouched'. It works fine if it's setup for a single author. For example

```
controller: @vouch = Vouch.last.vouched_user_nickname

view:

 <% Twitter::Search.new(params[:id]).each do |tweet| %>
   <li>
     <%= image_tag tweet.profile_image_url %> 

<% if @vouch.include? tweet.from_user %> <div class="flit_message_containerh">

            <u> <a href="http://twitter.com/<%= tweet.from_user %>"> <%= tweet.from_user %></a></u> <%= linkup_mentions(auto_link(h tweet.text)) %>
            <div class="time_ago">
          <%= link_to distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(tweet.created_at) , tweet %>
       <% else %>    <div class="flit_message_container">
    <u> <a href="http://twitter.com/<%= tweet.from_user %>"> <%= tweet.from_user %></a></u>
           <%= linkup_mentions(auto_link(h tweet.text)) %>
                <div class="time_ago">
              <%= link_to distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(tweet.created_at) , tweet %>
            <% end %>
```

But I'm having trouble doing it for multiple user nicknames.

```
@vouch =  Vouch.find(:all,
      :select => "vouched_user_nickname", 
      :group => 'vouched_user_nickname'                  

)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm a rails noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there isn't a relation between your `Vouch` model and the Twitter source (I haven't used that gem/plugin yet so I don't know), one solution is to pull all the Twitter entries you want and all the vouches in the controller and do the check in the view.

controller:

```
@tweets = Twitter::Search.new(params[:id])
@vouches = Vouch.find(:all)
```

view:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <div class="flit_message_container<%=
    @vouches.any? { |v| v.vouched_user_nickname == tweet.from_user } ? "h" : ""
  %>">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yay. that worked. really elegant and creative solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@vouch =  Vouch.find_by_vouched_user_nickname(:all, ["nickname1","nickname2"])
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. Do I need to change the view? Thanks.

Comment: Any other advice? I tried this in a few ways, it's not working.

Comment: You would need to do something different with @vouch(and maybe rename it to vouches) now, since it is an array, like `@vouches.each do |vouch|...` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you don't know the correct controller code to write to find the **@vouch** array? Or is it that you don't know what to do with the array once you get it?

```
 view: <% if @vouch.include? tweet.from_user %>
```

.include? is a method you can call on either a single object or an array of objects if tweet.from_user has an object that is also included in the @vouch array to get the @vouch array in your controller you should:

Comment: I am a noob so for the sake of simplicity, both those problems relate.

Comment: hmm, actually, I think my problem is that I don't know what to do with the array in the view. It seems to be grabbing the right data.

Comment: hmmm. that's not working either. I updated the main question with all the code in the view and the controller code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are not looping through the array, so how can it decide if certain elements meet the criteria  you set?

Example, in your view:

```
<% for vouch in @vouch do %>
  <% if vouch.include? tweet.from_user %>
    <div class="flit_message_containerh">
      <u><a href="http://twitter.com/<%= tweet.from_user %>"> <%= tweet.from_user %></a></u> <%= linkup_mentions(auto_link(h tweet.text)) %>
            <div class="time_ago">
          <%= link_to distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(tweet.created_at) , tweet %>
       <% else %>    <div class="flit_message_container">
    <u> <a href="http://twitter.com/<%= tweet.from_user %>"> <%= tweet.from_user %></a></u>
           <%= linkup_mentions(auto_link(h tweet.text)) %>
                <div class="time_ago">
              <%= link_to distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(tweet.created_at) , tweet %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This would repeat each tweet for each vouch in the database. Definitely not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems.
The first one is this:

```
@vouch = Vouch.last.vouched_user_nickname
```

You are using a variable called `@vouch` to store a user nickname. That is counterintuitive and will confuse other people reading your code (like myself). Use something like this instead:

```
@vouch = Vouch.last #on the controller
@vouch.vouched_used_nickname #on the view
```

This ... eum ... "exotic" naming convention helps confusing yourself when you try to do the "multiple" example:

```
@vouch =  Vouch.find(:all,
      :select => "vouched_user_nickname", 
      :group => 'vouched_user_nickname')
```

Activerecord's find(:all, ...) will allways return an array of activerecord objects (or an empty array). You seem to be expecting an array of strings. You will allways get Vouches if you do Vouch.find.

The :select part just limits the amount of information these vouches have (they only come with vouched_user_nickname populated. The rest, including their id, is empty, because it is not read from the database).

If you want to have an array of user nicknames you can do it like this:

```
# note the names. @vouchers in plural, and @nicknames for the user names
@vouchers =  Vouch.find(:all, :select => "vouched_user_nickname",
  :group => 'vouched_user_nickname')
@nicknames = @vouchers.collect{|v| v.vouched_user_nickname}
```